# TFS vs SVN commands

Tags: svn, tfs, tortoisesvn

I a developer using TFS 2010 for last 2 years for every thing from source control to work-item, merging, branch, shelvesets, gated- checkin, off-course checkin & checkout. I am pretty much familiar & comfortable with all of these.

Now I have to work on project ongoing on Tortoise SVN. I have no prior experience of using SVN. I have searched all for SVN & TFS-2010 analogous commands but no apt article is found except for cost & feature comparision for opting between two.

Can anyone share the SVN technical terms/ commands analogous to TFS ones?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are some of TFS terms and their analogues in SVN. It is important to note that SVN is only a soutrce control - there is not bug tracking or work tracking functionality (no work items, no project collections etc).

The list below is by no means a complete list of TFS or SVN terms. I've just named most of items that appeared in Tortoise SVN context menu and searched for corresponding terms in TFS.

```
         TFS               |            SVN
--------------------------------------------------------
Version                    | Revision
Get Latest Version         | Update
Check In (Pending Changes) | Commit
View History               | Show log
Source Control Explorer    | Repo browser
Compare*                   | Check for modifications
View History               | Revision graph
Resolve conflicts*         | Resolve
Get Specific Version       | Update to revision
Rename                     | Rename
Delete                     | Delete
Undo Pending Changes       | Revert
Undo Pending Changes*      | Clean up
Lock                       | Get Lock
Unlock                     | Release Lock
Branch                     | Branch/Tag
Move                       | Switch
Merge                      | Merge
Move                       | Relocate
Shelve*                    | Patch
```

`*` means it is not a direct analogue, just a similar concept. And of course it might be a good idea to check out all of these commands in more details in docs: for [Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) and for [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Andrei for prompt reply. This is exactly I was looking for.

Comment: SVN not having bug-tracking or other 'added extras' is a good thing in my view.  IMHO, I think SCM systems should stick to their primary goals!  There are plenty of better issue-management products out there (considerably better and cheaper per seat).

Comment: +1 for the terminology mapping through... I'm much more familiar with CVS/SVN/Mercurial and am struggling to remember the TFS terms!

Comment: @RayHayes, I believe it depends on the final goal. SVN aims to be a version control system, and so it does (does very well by the way). TFS + VS on the other hand is meant to be a complete platform containing almost everything a development team (devs, QAs, BAs etc) might need. Whether it is a good or bad aim is another question, but I think TFS performs what it is targeted to, at least at some level.

Comment: @Andrei, true, although I dislike its insistence in showing me artefacts that I don't want to manage, a .hgignore or being able to set better ignore meta-data would be better.  Additionally, putting all of the development process into a 'general purpose' solution from a single vendor has - in my experience - always lead to compromises in the way you work!

Comment: @Andrei,  FWIW, TFS 2012 now has something named [Local Workspaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx) that works much like SVN, including ability to ignore files.

Comment: @RyanRiehle, wasn't aware of local workspaces before, thanks for sharing! No more read-only files and less pain after going offline/online - excellent news. I might finally like TFS source control some day.

Comment: @RayHayes, I have yet to get familiar with SVN but TFS is what I learnt as first Source Control. At that time I was just considering what's available in TFS is standard or general, but now I know, that's not the case. Indeed TFS was meant for whole configuration management, project management, bug/ work-item tracking, continuous build, nightly builds & some how resource management. Too much for a single tool.

Comment: TFS has so many hidden configuration options I was amazed to explore. We can authorize different group of people with different permissions for some project or even directory. Also we can edit default templates for different type of work-item so that you're not available with artefacts you don't have to manage. Integration with MS Project, excel, default integration with VS is some thing I am missing in SVN.

Comment: Some confusions, in SVN check-out is equivalent to TFS Get Latest or Map to Local Folder. I have mapped one directory incorrectly, now unable to find the option like remove mapping. Any option rather than deleting folder & again check-out. Please Help?

Comment: @Pranav, your question would be best presented as a Stack Overflow question rather than hidden in these comments.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  I'm coming the other way, from SVN to TFS and this helps a lot!  Side note:  I miss SVN.  TFS is soooo slow and buggy!